# sem_open with initial value of 0 failing with EINVAL

Tags: c, linux, semaphore

I have this simple example which I've run on Linux:

```c
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#include <semaphore.h>

#define SEM_NAME "/some/sem/name"

int main() {
    sem_t *sem;

    sem = sem_open(SEM_NAME, O_CREAT, S_IRUSR, 0);
    if ( sem == SEM_FAILED ) {
        perror("sem_open");
        return 1;
    }

    sem_close(sem);
    sem_unlink(SEM_NAME);
    return 0;
}
```

Its output is:

```
sem_open: Invalid argument
```

Here are the possible causes of `EINVAL` as listed in the man page:

> **EINVAL**: value was greater than SEM_VALUE_MAX.
>
> **EINVAL**: name consists of just "/", followed by no other characters.

In my example, `value` is 0 and `name` is clearly not just `"/"`.  What am I missing?

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html or https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/sem_open.html have better descriptions of what names are allowed

Comment: Ah!  I didn't notice that "none of which are slashes" clause.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [the POSIX `sem_open()` documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/sem_open.html):

> ... The `name` argument conforms to the construction rules for a pathname, except that **the interpretation of `<slash>` characters other than the leading `<slash>` character in name is implementation-defined**, and that the length limits for the name argument are implementation-defined and need not be the same as the pathname limits `{PATH_MAX}` and `{NAME_MAX}`. If name begins with the `<slash>` character, then processes calling `sem_open()` with the same value of name shall refer to the same semaphore object, as long as that name has not been removed. If name does not begin with the `<slash>` character, the effect is implementation-defined.

Assuming you're on a Linux system, the Linux [`sem_open()` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_open.3.html) states:

> `sem_open()` creates a new POSIX semaphore or opens an existing
> semaphore.  The semaphore is identified by name.  For details of
> the construction of name, see [sem_overview(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html).

The [`sem_overview(7)` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html) states:

> **Named semaphores**
>
> A named semaphore is identified by a name of the form
> `/somename`; that is, a null-terminated string of up to
> `NAME_MAX-4` (i.e., 251) characters consisting of an initial
> slash, followed by one or more characters, **none of which
> are slashes.**

Note the bolded part:  "none of which are slashes".

Your

```
#define SEM_NAME "/some/sem/name"
```

defines an invalid semaphore name.

Answer (score 2):

As a side note, under Linux/glibc, the name is managed as follow (source code of glibc-2.34). First, the name parameter is passed to an internal function called __*shm_get_name()* (file *sysdeps/pthread/sem_open.c*):

```c
sem_t *
__sem_open (const char *name, int oflag, ...)
{
  int fd;
  sem_t *result;

  /* Check that shared futexes are supported.  */
  int err = futex_supports_pshared (PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
  if (err != 0)
    {
      __set_errno (err);
      return SEM_FAILED;
    }

  struct shmdir_name dirname;
  if (__shm_get_name (&dirname, name, true) != 0)
    {
      __set_errno (EINVAL);
      return SEM_FAILED;
    }
[...]
```

The function is defined in *posix/shm-directory.c*. It first gets rid of the heading "/" in the name and accept it unless there are still "/" characters in the rest of the name (cf. the call to `memchr()` in the last checks):

```c
int
__shm_get_name (struct shmdir_name *result, const char *name, bool sem_prefix)
{
  while (name[0] == '/')
    ++name;
  size_t namelen = strlen (name);

  struct alloc_buffer buffer
    = alloc_buffer_create (result->name, sizeof (result->name));
  alloc_buffer_copy_bytes (&buffer, SHMDIR, strlen (SHMDIR));
  if (sem_prefix)
    alloc_buffer_copy_bytes (&buffer, "sem.", strlen ("sem."));
  alloc_buffer_copy_bytes (&buffer, name, namelen + 1);
  if (namelen == 0 || memchr (name, '/', namelen) != NULL
      || alloc_buffer_has_failed (&buffer))
    return -1;
  return 0;
}
```

So, this is the latter function which made fail the OP's program as "/some/sem/name" still contains "/" characters when the heading one is removed. The following error branch in the `sem_open()` code is entered to set **errno** to **EINVAL** and return **SEM_FAILED**:

```c
  if (__shm_get_name (&dirname, name, true) != 0)
    {
      __set_errno (EINVAL);
      return SEM_FAILED;
    }
```

As a conclusion, in this context (Linux/glibc), the manual could be completed with:

**EINVAL** is returned if there are "/" characters after the first non "/" one in the name.